# SQL querying a customer ID who ordered both product A and B

Tags: sql, sqlite, self-join

Having a bit of trouble when trying to figure out how to return a query of a customer who ordered both A and B

[image]

What I'm looking for is  all customers who order both product A and product B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM table
WHERE product in ('a','b')
GROUP BY customerid
HAVING COUNT(distinct product) = 2
```

I don't normally post code only answers but there isn't a lot that words can add to this- the query predominantly explains itself

You can also

```
HAVING max(product) <> min(product)
```

It may be worth pointing out that in queries, the WHERE is performed, filtering to just products A and B. Then the GROUP BY is performed, grouping customer and counting the distinct number of products (or getting the min and max). Then the HAVING is performed, filtering to just those with 2 distinct products (or getting only those where MIN i.e. A, is different to MAX i.e. B)

If you'v never encountered HAVING, it is logically equivalent to:

```
SELECT CustomerID
FROM(
    SELECT CustomerID, COUNT(distinct product) as count_distinct_product
    FROM table
    WHERE product in ('a','b')
    GROUP BY customerid
)z
WHERE
     z.count_distinct_product = 2
```

In a HAVING clause you can only refer to columns that are mentioned in the group by. You can also refer to aggregate operations (such as count/min/max) on other columns not mentioned in the group by

Comment: you got it correct I missed the trick @Caius Jard even I was about to reach the same :) count(distinct product) did the trick

Comment: Isn't this assuming that there will only be one and only one record with customer X and product 'A' and one and only one record with customer X and product 'B' ?

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with SQLLite, but since it's specs say it is a Relational Database, it should allow the following query.

```
select CustomerID
  from table t
 where exists (
       select *
         from table
        where CustomerID = t.CustomerID
          and Product  = 'A'
       )
   and exists (
       select *
         from table
        where CustomerID = t.CustomerID
          and Product  = 'B'
       )
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select  customerid from table group by customerid having product like 'A' and product like 'B'` or 
you can try `having count(distinct product) =2`this seems to be more accurate.
The whole idea is in a group of customerid suppose 1 if I have several A's and B's count(distinct product) will give as 2 else it will be 1 so the answer is as above.

Comment: Can you please check with having count(distinct product) as in my second query and tell me if its working.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a correlated sub-query with a `HAVING` clause to scoop in both products in a single `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT
  t.Customer
FROM
  @t AS t
WHERE
  EXISTS
    (
      SELECT
        1
      FROM
        @t AS s
      WHERE
        t.Customer = s.Customer
        AND s.Product IN ('A', 'B')
      HAVING
        COUNT(DISTINCT s.Product) = 2
    )
GROUP BY
  t.Customer;
```

Comment: Why so complex?

Comment: @CaiusJard It's not really _that_ complex...but your answer is better. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way I just figured out was

```
SELECT CustomerID 
FROM table
WHERE product in ('a','b')
GROUP BY customerid
HAVING sum(case product ='a' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
    and sum(case when product ='b' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```