# Find users who have visited URL A and B with SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, having, having-clause

Let's say you have a table with `user, url, datetime`, in which each row is a website visit.

**How to find users who have visited both an URL contaning string pattern A and visited an URL containing string pattern B?**

The fact it's "containing a string pattern ...", and not a simple equality makes it impossible to use a query with something like

```
url in ('action1.php', 'action2.php')
```

like in [SQL querying a customer ID who ordered both product A and B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53268844/sql-querying-a-customer-id-who-ordered-both-product-a-and-b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `having`:

```
select user
from t
where url like '%a%' or
      url like '%b%'
group by user
having sum(url like '%a%') > 0 and
       sum(url like '%b%') > 0;
```

If you don't want to repeat the comparisons, you can leave out the `where` clause or use:

```
select user
from (select t.*, (url like '%a%') as has_a, (url like '%n%') as has_b
      from t
     ) t
where has_a or has_b
group by user
having sum(has_a) > 0 and
       sum(has_b) > 0;
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, you answered quickly! It works! PS: do you think it's possible to do it without duplicating the patterns `%a%` and `%b%` (which can be long) in the query?

Comment: @Basj . . . Yes.  You can leave out the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "/testing" and "/staging" are the two URL patterns. You can use this

```
SELECT   user
FROM     `table`
WHERE    url LIKE '%/testing%' or
         url LIKE '%/staging%'
GROUP BY user
HAVING   (COUNT(url LIKE '%/testing%') > 0 and COUNT(url LIKE '%/staging%') > 0)
```

If you need more info on pattern matching you can do a search on "pattern matching SQL" and "SQL regular expression".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not exactly an answer ("Just do a google research"), maybe can you edit to include a more precise answer, maybe with an example query? All the best to you on SO.

Comment: @Basj, sorry about that, I thought matching the pattern was the main problem and I didn't want to copy and paste information that was readily available online. I've made changes to my answer.